# Distorted pixel extra bright from an angle

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I have a pixel on my laptop screen that looks slightly greyish and the area around looks distorted, but it isn't dead. When I tilt the laptop, this pixel shines out brightly. Any ideas to fix this? The machine is touchscreen (hp-ab048tx)

Comment: Hard to be sure without some images, but it sounds like the kind of symptom you can get from physical damage; something sharp pressing on the screen in that spot.  If that's the case, there isn't any way to fix it other than replacing the screen.  There's no risk in just leaving it alone (it won't damage anything else or get worse by itself).

Comment: Thanks, if it wouldn't get worse, I guess I'll let it stay